# define a long array in jquery click function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have  following long type session on server side code

```
long[] grouparray = ..;

Session["grouplist"] = grouparray;
```

Now I'm trying to get this session on View Page's jquery click function

```
$("#gpline").click(function () {

    parseInt(@Session["grouplist"]);
    var grouplistvalues = Session["grouplist"];

    alert(grouplistvalues);

});
```

But this is having error once I debug using firebug

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']'
>
> parseInt(System.Int64[]);

Comment: You seem confused about the separation between client side and server side code. You need to output the server side code to the client in a manner which is expected. Calling server side constructs, such as the `Session` is not going to work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this seems like MVC razor syntax, If So then server side code can be used in the Views.

Comment: True, but you'd need to prefix it with `@`, and even then you need to serialise the array of `long` so that JS can understand it

Comment: @kez is your view a `asp.net mvc` razor page?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes that is right..

Comment: @Reddy yes its asp.net mvc 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Json.Encode` and `@Html.Raw` on your c# data to make it compatible with your scripts.

Try this.

```
$("#gpline").click(function () {

    var grouplistvalues = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["grouplist"])); // converting the session data into array of numbers in javascript variable

    alert(JSON.stringify(grouplistvalues)); // stringify is used only to test.

});
```

Comment: :) if it fixed the issue you can mark it as answer. @kez

Comment: system requires to stay another 5 minutes to accept it :D

Comment: @kez I can wait :) happy coding!!

Comment: If I want to assign this `grouplistvalues` to a `Session["grouplist"]` how to do it can I do like this `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["grouplist"])) = grouplistvalues`

Comment: @kez No you cannot. Let me explain the behind the scenes work flow. When you hit a controller and return a view what actually happen is the server will fetch the view, Attach the master page, convert all the c# variables in the .cshtml page into its actual values and at the end gives you one complete HTML page. Right from `<!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body></body></html>`. So This means the response from the server will be plain HTML as good as written in a notepad. So the above solution works as the code would have changed into something like `var grouplistvalues =  [12,3456,1321,13213,...]`

Comment: @kez Now to do the reverse that is to set a value to server side variable `Session` you cannot do as you are asking. You will have to send the data to server using `ajax` and then inside the server code you can assign the sent data to your session.